# Why doesn't my numpy code for generating correlated, normally distributed variables preserve the covariance?

Tags: python, random-generation, scipy, numpy

I'm trying to generate random variables whose correlation matches some existing data.  My coding skills are good, my statistics, not so much...  I'm trying to follow this [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/446098).

I know that...

1. ...there is `numpy.random.multivariate_normal()`.  Using it in the code below does preserve the covariance matrix.  However, I can't use `multivariate_normal()` because this code is a sketch for a from-scratch C++ implementation I need to write.
2. ...Cholesky would be better, but the actual data is much larger and the covariance matrix I get is not positive semi-definite due to numerical issues (some eigenvectors are extremely small and negative), so I'm using LU.

Here's my code in `numpy` + `pandas` + `scipy`:

```py
print("original data:")
display(data)
cov = data.cov()
print("means:")
means = data.mean()
display(means)
print("Covariance matrix:")
display(cov)

lu = sp.linalg.lu(cov)
print("Lu composition:")
display(lu)
r_vecs = []
C = lu[2]
for i in range(0,1000): 
    r = np.random.rand(4)
    r = np.array(means + np.matmul(C,r))
    r_vecs.append(r)
r_vecs = np.array(r_vecs).transpose()
print("Random vectors")
display(r_vecs)
cov = np.cov(r_vecs)
print("New Covariance:")
display(cov)
```

Which yields the output below.  As you can see, the new covariance matrix matrix isn't close to the original.

```
original data:
state_id    1   2   3   4
fips    1   1   1   1
year                
2010    41.5    28.3    38.1    48.4
2011    41.5    28.0    39.4    48.2
2012    50.5    34.1    47.1    49.4
2013    51.1    25.5    44.0    45.8
2014    37.6    33.7    37.0    53.2
2015    44.7    34.5    40.1    51.2
2016    44.1    31.0    41.0    50.0
2017    53.1    33.3    47.0    46.5
2018    40.6    35.5    37.1    51.1
2019    47.0    30.3    43.3    50.8
2020    50.7    32.8    46.2    48.9
2021    48.2    30.3    43.5    50.2
2022    45.1    32.2    41.0    50.4
2023    52.3    30.9    49.8    48.7
2024    44.0    30.9    38.0    50.8
means:
state_id  fips
1         1       46.133333
2         1       31.420000
3         1       42.173333
4         1       49.573333
dtype: float64
Covariance matrix:
state_id    1   2   3   4
fips    1   1   1   1
state_id    fips                
1   1   22.453810   -1.412857   18.054524   -5.805476
2   1   -1.412857   7.447429    -0.330857   2.945571
3   1   18.054524   -0.330857   16.397810   -4.115762
4   1   -5.805476   2.945571    -4.115762   3.613524
Lu composition:
(array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1.]]),
 array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-0.06292283,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.80407397,  0.10942196,  1.        ,  0.        ],
        [-0.25855195,  0.35065092,  0.15058683,  1.        ]]),
 array([[22.45380952, -1.41285714, 18.05452381, -5.80547619],
        [ 0.        ,  7.35852761,  0.80518451,  2.58027446],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.79253199,  0.26993171],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.16708286]]))
Random vectors
array([[74.70193365, 55.03466033, 68.22871498, ..., 49.0980958 ,
        72.27992542, 61.92792275],
       [35.27782613, 37.58347528, 38.53579669, ..., 39.0202239 ,
        36.12145166, 38.50875726],
       [43.08390251, 42.38530212, 42.8831479 , ..., 42.38918521,
        43.18383282, 42.86036086],
       [49.66537614, 50.05016775, 49.95270184, ..., 50.42280749,
        49.98598684, 50.13783394]])
New Covariance:
array([[ 7.18379697e+01, -1.30034112e+00,  2.53202396e+00,
        -6.46181988e-01],
       [-1.30034112e+00,  5.08084225e+00,  1.55444340e-01,
         2.53355942e-01],
       [ 2.53202396e+00,  1.55444340e-01,  2.70450328e-01,
         1.95828853e-02],
       [-6.46181988e-01,  2.53355942e-01,  1.95828853e-02,
         1.06479811e-01]])
```